# URLEncode in Smarty

Tags: smarty

I wrote a Code to short my URL but have Problem during the URL encoding because the URL calls an ID with **`{$CWunschliste->cURLID}`**

```
{php}$short = file_get_contents('http://ur.l/api.php?url=' . urlencode({$ShopURL}/index.php?wlid={$CWunschliste->cURLID}));{/php}

{php}$url=json_decode($short,TRUE);{echo $url['short'];}{/php}
```

How can I rewrite the url encode to call `{$CWunschliste->cURLID}` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `{php}` tags in Smarty templates you should place there PHP code, so you cannot use Smarty syntax. Your code should probably look like this:

```
{php}
$short = file_get_contents('http://ur.l/api.php?url=' . urlencode($this->getTemplateVars('ShopURL').'/index.php?wlid='.$this->getTemplateVars('CWunschliste')->cURLID));

$url=json_decode($short,TRUE);
echo $url['short'];
{/php}
```

**However you shouldn't do it this way. You should do such things in PHP. Smarty is just for displaying views and not for getting data from remote urls or other model tasks.**

In addition `{php}` tag is deprecated and can be used only in SmartyBC class.

**EDIT**

I forgot to remove `{` from answer ( already fixed it) but even in this case I got the following error

> Using $this when not in object context

That's really strange because if you look at [Smarty php tag example](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl) in this example $this is used to access Smarty object.

However the working solution would be changing `$this` into `$template` ( I have to emphasise $template is in this case not the name of Smarty object created in PHP - I've created Smarty object `$smarty` but in `{php}` tags I have to access Smarty using `$template`).

The following code should work for you:

```
{php}
$short = file_get_contents('http://ur.l/api.php?url=' . urlencode($template->getTemplateVars('ShopURL').'/index.php?wlid='.$template->getTemplateVars('CWunschliste')->cURLID));

$url=json_decode($short,TRUE);
echo $url['short'];
{/php}
```

Comment: I would try to do it in PHP as a Noob but the System I am using is Hardcoded :( Using `$this->getTemplateVars` the Code is not running.